# "Too much recursion" backbone error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, models, backbone-model

I am using BackboneJS for my application. In my scenario, I have a collection (say `booksCollection`) with list of all the books (say model `Book`). I need to get a certain book based on the `id` and pass it to a view. I have the following code:

```
var book = booksCollection.get(1);
book.save(); // this obtained model is passed to some view, which makes few changes to the model and saves to the server

// booksCollection is a Backbone collection with model: Book
```

On inspecting `book`, I see that it has `collection` attribute with  all the models in `booksCollection`. So, when trying to save (after setting few attributes) this model, I get this error "Too much recursion".

Is the model retured by invoking `get` method on a `Backbone` collection a `readonly` object?

As a quick fix, I am unsetting the `collection` attribute in `book` and then saving the model

> book.unset('collection', { silent: true });

Is this a right approach?

Thanks,
Anji

Comment: The `model.collection` property is just a reference to the collection, to which the model belongs. This is normal and expected. The code you describe looks fine. The error is caused by something else - a method that calls itself, or two methods, who keep calling each other, infinitely until the maximum call stack size is reached. I would look into your event triggers and listeners, can they lead into a situation where a triggers b, and b handler triggers a?

Comment: @fencliff I do not have any events in my `Model` or `Collection`. They are very simple objects.

Comment: How about views? Do you have a `change` handler on any models? In any case the error is not related to the code you posted so far.

Comment: I do not have any `Views`, just a simple collection and model

Comment: OK. If there's not much code, can you just post all of in a jsfiddle? Here's a fiddle with Backbone already loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/QqLT3/

Comment: @fencliff Hey I figured out the problem, yes you were right about some events causing the problem. Thanks a lot!